# HTML/CSS - Bigger box within a smaller one

Tags: html, css

I thought if I make a box bigger than its container, the box will be restricted to the size of the container and there will be scroll bars around it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Amnesiac/ekT3h/

But the box actually comes out of the container as in the above example.

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you have to use css overflow to make the scrollbars appear. and you have to have content for them to be active, define the div as big as you actually want it to be displayed.

Updated your fiddle with an example http://jsfiddle.net/ekT3h/2/ made everything bigger for it to be easier to understand. A second fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ekT3h/4/ marked with names for divs and updated your original css to position the child irrespective of any other content.

Comment: Why is it that in my original fiddle the child box comes out of the container?

Comment: That's how the box model is defined, you can hide the overflow if you wish as suggested by prady, or you can add the scrollbars to your container div like @SudipPal suggested, but unless you can state more exactly what you're trying to accomplish that's all I can tell you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a "overflow:auto" property in your "container" class.

```
#container{
 height:100px;   
 width: 100px;   
 border: 1px solid red;  
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply following css:

```
overflow:hidden
```

Comment: That's not what he asked, that just hides the extra stuff, he wants scrollbars.